# How to display these Bootstrap elements from Inline into Vertical or vice versa for small and large screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to display these Bootstrap elements in 2 different formats for more responsiveness:

1. Format-1: when the screen is large enough then display them in inline (figure given below).
   [image]
2. Format-2: when the screen is small then display them in Vertical (figure given below).
   [image]

Here is the code given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">  
  <form class="form-inline" role="form">
     <div class="form-group">       
        <div class="row form-group ">   
            <label for="birthday" class="col-xs-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
               <label for="form-input-col-xs-2" class="wb-inv">Administrative Job:</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-input-col-xs-2" placeholder="job" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
               <label for="form-input-col-xs-3" class="wb-inv"> Effective Date:</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-input-col-xs-3" placeholder="date" />
            </div>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
              <label for="form-input-col-xs-4" class="wb-inv">Payroll Amount:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-input-col-xs-4" placeholder="amount" />
           </div>        
        </div>      
    </div>  
  </form>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

please suggest me on, what modification is needed to do that? please let me know for any further information.Thanks

Comment: It's all [in here](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/), 5005768.

Comment: And, for the record, SO is not a free coding service provider. Your question doesn't qualify as coding error, but as coding need from where I see it. We're here to help you hone your coding skills, not do it for you. I pointed you at the exact documentation you need for this and also suggested the solution to the problems you might have, in my comment under Nikhil's response. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @Andrei Gheorghiu .thanks. i understand that  SO is not a free coding service provider.Moreover i am a beginner on bootstrap.i've read the docs you suggested.So in my understanding according that document for my inline style, i have do 3 nested cols in 1 col .But for  vertical style, How to do 3 nested row in 1 cols. still  i am not getting it.thanks

Comment: I appreciate the effort, I'll give you an answer on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle of Bootstrap is pretty simple: you can divide any element in 12 equal parts, by giving it a class of `.row` and its imediate children classes of `.col-XX-N`, where `XX` are the device size selector and `N` is the number of columns from the total of 12. If the children sum up more than 12, a new row starts. Well, it's not that simple, but that's the starting point and the most important part.

Example:

```css
[class^="col-"] {padding: 10px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">I'm a quarter (3/12) on screens larger than 1200px, a third (4/12)on screens between 992px and 1200px, half (6/12) on screens between 768px and 991px and full (because we didn't specify a col-xs) on screens up to 767px</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">I'm a quarter (3/12) on screens larger than 1200px, a third (4/12)on screens between 992px and 1200px, half (6/12) on screens between 768px and 991px and full (because we didn't specify a col-xs) on screens up to 767px</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">I'm a quarter (3/12) on screens larger than 1200px, a third (4/12)on screens between 992px and 1200px, half (6/12) on screens between 768px and 991px and full (because we didn't specify a col-xs) on screens up to 767px</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">I'm a quarter (3/12) on screens larger than 1200px, a third (4/12)on screens between 992px and 1200px, half (6/12) on screens between 768px and 991px and full (because we didn't specify a col-xs) on screens up to 767px</div>
</div>
```

In order to test it, go full screen and resize the browser.

If the direct parent of `col-...` is 100%, you don't have to wrap them in a `.row`, but it's recommended, as Bootstrap has a few smart margins rules you don't want to break for no reason.

In your particular case, you want to ask yourself first: where do I want to change the layout? At 1200px (you'd use `col-lg-...`s), at 992px (you'd use `col-md-...`s) or at 768px (you've guessed: `col-sm-...`s!)?

Let's say you want to change it at 992px. Your form will look like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form role="form">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="job-input" class="wb-inv">Administrative Job:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="job-input" placeholder="job" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date-input" class="wb-inv">Effective Date:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date-input" placeholder="date" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="payroll-input" class="wb-inv">Payroll Amount:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="payroll-input" placeholder="amount" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

If, for example, you wanted your groups to be half the screen width in between 992 and 768px, you want to add to that `col-md-4` a `col-sm-6`:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
```

But that means that your last group will be alone on a row, right? Let's center it. On the last of the `cols`, the one holding the `payroll-input`, add also the class `col-sm-offset-3` which tells the column to offset itself by 3 columns on screens between 768px and 992px. But you also want to add `.col-md-offset-0` so the offset is not automatically applyed to all classes above `sm`. Try it:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form role="form">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="job-input" class="wb-inv">Administrative Job:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="job-input" placeholder="job" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date-input" class="wb-inv">Effective Date:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date-input" placeholder="date" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-0">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="payroll-input" class="wb-inv">Payroll Amount:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="payroll-input" placeholder="amount" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Last, but not least, a very nice addition to forms are input addons. You can use them to add buttons, dropdowns or even the labels as prefixes or sufixes of your inputs. Let's use your form and put the labels at the start of the inputs:

```css
form {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.input-group-addon {
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form role="form">
  <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="job-addon">Administrative Job</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="job-input" aria-describedby="job-addon" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Effective Date</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date-input" aria-describedby="date-addon" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <label class="input-group-addon">Payroll Amount</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="payroll-input" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the bootstrap grid system, you can use different classes like `col-sm, col-lg` etc to display elements differently on different screens.

So modify:

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
```

to

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
```

This will display the `div` to 3 columns on large screens and will change it to 12 columns for very small screens, hence stacking them or displaying them vertically.

Similarly you have to do some changes to the label as well since the classes have now being modified.

Read more about it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

This solution works fine for Large & Small screen with good amount of spaces.
However when the screen size get Medium,then these elements get cluttered without any gap space among them (like given below)is possible to do the same vertical style when  screen is **Medium**.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried your suggestion, Nikhil? he's having `col-xs-2`'s on labels... I suggest wrapping each label + input in a `col-md-4` (or `col-lg-4`).

Comment: Hey @AndreiGheorghiu, I just gave the overall idea about using different classes for different devices, offcourse specific changes are required at different places. However I will edit the answer to express the same, thanks

Comment: FYI, i didn't vote you down. I wonder who that might be... :)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu No issues :)

Comment: Hi @Nikhil Batra  the solution works ok.However i edited your post for further  solution for  Medium.

Comment: ok thanks @user5005768. Hope my answer helped you to understand the  overall concept behind it which was my main motive.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing classes that aren't (generally) for the type of layout your trying to build. You don't need (and shouldn't in general) mix classes such as `form-group` and `row` together as well as `columns` with an `inline-form`.

Based on the images you have a basic layout. See the example Snippet and refer to the [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="admin">Administrative Job:</label>
          <input id="admin" type="text" class="form-control" id="one" placeholder="Job" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="date">Effective Date:</label>
          <input id="date" type="text" class="form-control" id="two" placeholder="Date" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="payroll">Payroll Amount:</label>
          <input id="payroll" type="text" class="form-control" id="three" placeholder="Amount" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please point me to the Bootstrap documentation where mixing columns with form layout classes is discouraged, please?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Did I state anything as a quote from the documentation in my answer because I don't see anything that identifies as one but it seems like you're misquoting me because I stated "columns with an inline-form", not "form layout"  as you suggest. On a sidenote; you have  `class="wb-inv col-xs-12">` in your first two examples which seems out of place.

Comment: Correct, I missed that one. Thanks. And my question was genuine. Maybe too formal, but I thought you knew something I don't.